# Proving that $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ is finer than $\Bbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

Let us take the two topologies $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ and $\Bbb{R}$. The book "General Topology" by Munkres says that $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ is finer than $\Bbb{R}$. [This article](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Finer_topology) says that every open set of $\Bbb{R}$ has to be an open set in $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ for the latter to be finer than the former.

The basis of $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ consists of sets of the form $[a,b)$, where $a,b\in \Bbb{R}$. Similarly, the basis of $\Bbb{R}$ consists of sets of the form $(a,b)$.

How can any open set in $\Bbb{R}_\ell$ ever be of the form $(a,b)$? I have tried both all possible unions of the basis sets, and they all seem to be of the form $[a,b)$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it is not only finer, but also *properly* finer.

Comment: @drhab: Good point, but that's the easier of the two things to prove, since $[a,b)$ is never open in $\Bbb R$ for $a<b$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic open sets aren’t the only open sets: every **union** of basic open sets is open as well, and

$$(a,b)=\bigcup_{a<x<b}[x,b)$$

is a union of basic open sets in $\Bbb R_\ell$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Suppose that $a<b.$ Then what is the following set (which will be open in $\Bbb R_\ell,$ as a union of basic open sets)? $$\bigcup_{c\in (a,b)}[c,b)$$